# Lion Sandboxing crash report location

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, crash-reports, appstore-sandbox

I've just sandboxed my application for Lion and noticed that the crash reports are still being sent to ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter.  Is there a way to have them be saved in the Container Logs directory?